# How do I send a POST request with rails API (mongo db backend)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, api, rest

building a custom rails api for a rails/react/mongodb app.

GET requests working fine, but I can't get post to work.

Basically the params are not getting assigned to the object in my create method.

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/movies HTTP/1.1

{"title" : "Cool Movie"}
```

Here's my controller:

```
            def create
                movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
                if movie.save
                    render json: MovieBlueprint.render(movie) 
                else
                    render json: { error: movie.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
                end
            end

            private

            def movie_params
                params.except(:format).permit(:title, :description, :director, :genre)
            end
```

output:

```
  Parameters: {"{\"title\" : \"Cool Movie\"}"=>nil}
  Unpermitted parameter: :{"title" : "Cool Movie"}
```

I get a 200 response with this. Basically the document is getting created in the database, but the fields / values are all still null. Why is it telling me unpermitted params?

And I know typically with rails you have to require the object like so:

```
params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :description, :director, :genre)
```

But when I try this, it makes matters worse, I get a 400 - bad request with this:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: movie):
```

I assume this has something to do with the whole mongo thing and how I'm formatting my request, but I can't quite place it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance and considering the params coming into the controller via a `POST` request needs to reference the entity it's changing, your data would need to should look like this to be available in the `create` method:

```json
{  "movie": { "title": "Updated Song Title" } }
```

Depending on the version of Rails being used, you could add a `debugger` to test if the params are available. This will stop the runtime of the script and allow you to inspect it in the terminal.

> Run your server in an individual process before trying this. For example, instead of running `bin/dev` run `bin/rails server -p 3000`.

First, modify your create method to use `debugger`:

```rb
def create
    movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
    debugger # <- Stop the script right here.
    if movie.save
        render json: MovieBlueprint.render(movie) 
    else
        render json: { error: movie.errors.full_messages }, status: 422
    end
end
```

Then, run the `create` action of your controller by making a request to that endpoint with your `params` of choice. Navigating to your terminal you'll see the program has stopped and you can type. Type `params.inspect` to see if the `movie` key is present:

```rb
params.inspect
```

Type `continue` to let the rest of the program run.